# How can I pipe out output to file from terminal without linefeeds?

Tags: command-line

I have below command which output the result as newlines in every key press.
I don't want it to output to file as new lines instead I want it to send it to file without linefeeds.

```
 stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11 >out
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please tell us what exactly do you want. Because `stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11`, output nothing for me. I though you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try add `echo -n`

```
stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11 | xargs echo -n > out
```

**Update**

As i understand from your comment, you want not just remove linefeed, but also output log on every keypress using xinput.

First check all input devices:

```
   c0rp@c0rp:~$ xinput --list
```

This is a list of all available input devices

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Now if you want to test device, use `test` key, and as  parameter use id from second column.

For example, i use wireless keyboard, id=14:

```
xinput --test 14
```

Here is output:

```
key press   42 
key press   43 
key release 43 
key release 42 
key press   44
```

**And finaly what you want is...**

Sorry, on this step i realize that xinput cannot redirect stdout or stderr, it just buffered. [Proof link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59669/can-a-command-line-program-prevent-its-output-being-redirected).

So the only way to do what you want using `xinput` is:

Write xinput to a file `xinput test 11 > out`, then substitute all newlines using `tr`

```
tr -d '\n' < yourfile.txt
```

or if it doesn't work use same for DOS/Windows line endings

```
tr -d "\n\r" < yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I don't know why, it doesn't write to file. Text output file is empty.

Comment: I update answer

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I already knew that, I want to know if it's possible while piping out to file. You say it's not possible. I think I must resort to your last solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to either pipe it though `tr` or run `tr` on the final file. You can either replace the new lines with spaces

```
tr '\n' ' '
```

Or delete them all together

```
tr -d '\n'
```

For example:

```
stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11 | tr -d '\n' >out
```

Comment: I tried your command, it doesn't write to file. Text output file is empty.

Comment: and without the tr you are sure you get an output exactly as you typed it above? As the tr should just remove new lines.

Comment: Yes this `stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11 >out` outputs to file but not with this `stdbuf -o0 xinput test 11 | tr -d '\n' >out`